# put an image in a command button

Tags: visualforce, css, commandbutton

I'm trying to put an image inside a apex:command button, but I'm doing somenthig wrong. The button is simply empty. Someone could give me an advice pleace?. Below you find my code;

```
.buttonClass {  
  background-image:url('http://free-121d5f44d20-121d603d1c5-121ee2b8103.force.com/img/chatterfiles/chatterfiles16_sprite.png');
  width:50px;
  height:25px
}    

<apex:commandButton action="{!saveProducts}" value="" styleClass="buttonClass" id="SaveChanges" reRender="productstable"  />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store the required image in static resource and use it in command button in the following way

```
<apex:commandbutton image="{!URLFOR($Resource.Required_Image)}" id="SaveChanges" reRender="productstable" action="{!saveProducts}"/>﻿
```